# PHP $_GET returns 'index' when there is extension in URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get

I have the following line in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([a-z\-]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

In most cases, everything works as it should. But, if I add any extension to the URL, `var_dump($_GET["page"]);` displays `string(5) "index"`

For example: **mywebsite.com/mypge**

If I `var_dump($_GET["page"]);`, 'mypage' will be displayed.

On the other hand, **mywebsite.com/mypge.php**, will display 'index'

I need only .php extension to work, and to be detected "normally".

So, if I have **mywebsite.com/mypge.php**, I need to get mypage.php

Can you please help me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression does not allow for a `.` 
This should work:

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-z.\-]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Even better: ^([a-z.\-]+)\/?$  (escape the slash).